# Need to find the equation of a curve from a Hand drawing

Tags: geometry, curves, applications

My uncle makes hand drawings of furniture on a large piece of chart paper at 1:1 scale. He has recently passed away. I have the task of converting those hand drawings into Autocad drawings. The straight lines are easy to draw. But the curves of the furniture are very hard to replicate exactly. I need to be as precise as possible.

Currently, I mark points on the curve and measure the distance from a reference line and then recreate that on the computer. This is extremely time-consuming.

Is there a mathematical way in which I can solve this problem? Either by getting the equation of the curve or something?

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I don't think that a mathematics community is really the right community to answer it.  There is not an AutoCAD SE site (there seems to have been a proposal for one in the past, but it failed to attract much interest), but there are [questions about CAD](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cad) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Doesn't Autocad support freeform curves and splines ?

Comment: It does support splines, not sure how to get the points that define the curve. I can get as many points from the real drawing but how do I ensure that it is accurate ?

Comment: This isn't a mathematics question, and you're going about it the wrong way. You want to find the simplest way to approximate those hand-drawn curves, since you certainly don't want to trace every slight imperfection. So you should not be reproducing exactly the positions of sampled points. Rather, you should try to figure out the ideas behind the curves. Most of the time, the curves that humans draw are either circular, conical, or close to cubic splines, so you just have to figure out where each piece starts and solve equations to make them join smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your CAD software does not support freeform curves (which I doubt), go for natural cubic splines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines

You will define the curves from a set of interpolating points. When there are angular points, start a new spline (which they didn't do in the example below).

[image]

Note that cubic splines can be converted to cubic Beziers, which are quite commonplace. (You can also try Beziers straight away, but fitting to an existing curve can be more difficult.)

Comment: Does using a larger set of interpolation points make the curve more accurate? , is there a way to find the minimum number of points that I would need to pick from the drawing to make it as accurate as possible.

Comment: "as accurate as possible" does not really make sense, you'd better say as "as accurate as useful". Yes, more points mean better accuracy, but I don't know how fast, unfortunately.

Comment: This method seems good as I have a cad software that has splines. I will then cross check it with original drawing and see if it matches as close as possible.

Comment: I suppose the point is to preserve the designs, so that the same furniture can be reproduced in the future. Typically, the processes used to manufcature furniture are only accurate to around 0.1 mm or so, so there is no point in replicating the curves any more accurately than this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Freedom Tower in $Iran-Tehran$.[image]

And this is how I drew it with 202 equations:
[image]

Go to [www.desmos.com](http://desmos.com) and paste your picture in the background and try to trace the equation over that. At the beginning it may take some times but it will be easier as you practice more.

And these are the first 58 equations that I wrote, if you need the rest of them I can send them to you:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Seyed. A quick question " Will the dimensions still remain the same ?". The reason behind this is that the drawings that I make will be further used for production of the furniture.

Comment: @HussainBhavnagarwala, the coordinates of $x$ and $y$ are in scale.

Comment: How is this an answer ? You tell nothing about the equations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, do I have to post all 202 equations in here?

Comment: I am not sure how to use desmos yet , but will give it a try !! @Seyed could you guide me in the direction to learn this software.

Comment: @HussainBhavnagarwala, You need to follow the instructions in that site and practice.

Comment: Haha, good joke ! What is the functional form ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what is your problem? Trying to be funny?

Comment: @Seyed: why don't you want to give the equation, which is what the OP was asking ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Frist of all the OP never asked for the equations, are you awake? Second of all, I asked you how can I write all the 202 equations in here? If you are really interested yourself to have the equations why don't you ask it? Give me your email address so I can send it to you. It is in a pdf format.

Comment: The title is "Need to find the equation of a curve from a Hand drawing". I understand that you have no idea of the functional form of the equations you use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, And I showed him one of the ways available to write the equation of any curve. I also understand that you have some issues with yourself which causes you to behave this way. You must understand that we are all here to help each other with whatever we know and not to make fun and joke of other people. I am not going to waste my time with you anymore and from now on you are ignored by my.

Comment: So far, I haven't seen a single equation. You don't answer the OP's question. Trying to discredit me isn't helpful.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I added the first 58 equations to my answer just to satisfy your not very pleasant and friendly behavior. If you know how to plot an equation, you can plot some of them and compare it with the picture.

Comment: It was enough to say line segments and circular arcs. You can discard these 58 equations that only relate to your case, and state the functional form. Anyway, the continuity conditions and/or the computational procedure would still be missing. In other words, the OP can do nothing with this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, you are ignored.

Comment: I invite you to read a little on analytical geometry and interpolation techniques. Interesting topics.

Answer (score 0):

If You can guess the curve could be approximately the graph of a rational function of say degree $n$ i.e. the graph of a function of the form
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$$
where $a_j\in\mathbb{R}$ for $j=0,...,n$ and $a_n\neq 0$ and in Your case $n\geq 2$ and You find $n+1$ points on the curve $P_1(x_1,y_1),...,P_{n+1}(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ after a suitable choice of Your coordiante system, You get a system of linear equations
$$f(x_j)=a_nx_j^n+a_{n-1}x_j^{n-1}+...+a_0=y_j,j=1,...,n+1$$
that You can solve ( if it is solvable ) by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Since the curve is hand drawn its not just a single smooth curve, its more like a spline with multiple node points. From the little mathematics that I know you are asking to find the order of the equation and then use n+1 points and then after that I am a bit lost. Is it possible to dumb it down a bit. I am not sure what is gaussian elimination or if I understood the last equation correctly.

Comment: I didn´t see the curve, but if it is for example piecewise smooth as I would suggest if it is about furniture, You could guess the degree ( piecewise)If You solve this system of linear equations You automatically get the equation to the curve namely $y=a_nx^n+...+a_0$, however this is only an idea how such a problem could be tackled mathematically and as pointed out in the comments using autocad or similar programs is much better suited to Your task

Comment: Polynomial and rational interpolation quickly become unstable when then number of points increases. Piecewise interpolation is better behaved.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's true only with equispaced nodes, as far as I know.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: it is in general worse with non-uniform points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not so sure. Chebyshev interpolants seem to work rather well. See for instance https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythspaper.pdf , or https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/11/06/chebyshev-interpolation/ for the classical Runge example.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I said *in general*, not when the placement of the points is ad-hoc. Polynomial interpolation works poorly with arbitrary points.

Comment: There are two problems with polynomial interpolation. One is a mathematical problem, related to poles in the complex plane. This can be addressed by interpolating at properly-spaced locations (e.g. Chebyshev zeros or extrema), not at equally-spaced points. The other problem is computational, and results from the ill-conditioning of calculations that use power basis coefficients or Vandermonde matrices. This can be avoided just by using some other polynomial basis (e.g. Chebyshev or Bernstein). Both problems are covered nicely in Trefethen's book "Approximation Theory and Practice".

Comment: Anyone who doubts the effectiveness of polynomial interpolation should play with the chebfun system.